# Python requests module - how do I change the Response objects language?

Tags: python-requests

How do I change the language of a downloaded web page using the requests module? I would like to change the language to English. I tried changing the headers accept language but it did not change anything.

Here is my code:

```
#! python3
# lucky.py - Opens several Google search results.    
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
print('Please enter your search term:')
searchTerm = input()
print('Googling...')    # display text while downloading the Google page

url = 'http://google.com.au/search?q=' + ' '.join(searchTerm)
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.55", "Cache-Control": "no-cache, max-age=0", 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()


# Retrieve top search results links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

# Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('.r > a')  
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))    
for i in range(numOpen):
  webbrowser.open(linkElems[i].get('href'))
  print(linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: Why you send request to `www.google.com.au` instead of `www.google.com`?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/how-to-restrict-a-google-search-to-results-of-a-specific-language

Comment: That was one of my attempts to try to change the language.  I just found that changing the url to this works:                                                            
url = 'http://google.com.au/search?hl=en&sou&q=' + ' '.join(searchTerm)

Comment: That stackexchange link is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`gl=two-letter country code`, `hl=two-letter language code`. [Supported Google Languages](https://serpapi.com/google-languages) (`gl` param), and [Supported Google Countries](https://serpapi.com/google-countries)(`hl` param).

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft&gl=us&hl=en
>>> Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft

https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft&gl=de&hl=de
>>> Offizielle Seite | Minecraft
```

That tranlates to:

```py
params = {
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  # other params 
}

requests.get("URL", params=params)
```

---

Alternatively, you can achive the same thing by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to maintain the parser, figure out how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines, or figure out what availabe parameters out there.

Example code:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Coffee",
  "location": "Austin, Texas, United States",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for title in results["organic_results"]:
    print(title["title"], sep="\n")
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.